# PHP Regex Match those which start with Capital letter

Tags: php, regex

It sounds pretty simple but I cant figure this out, please help me out.

So... I have file with following data:

```
Name: Santi
Surname: Dore
Name: Rob
Surname: Doe
and so on..
```

I need to match only the whole part that starts with "Name:" ... NOT "Surname:" ...

Here is what I am using right now to match it:

```
/Name(:)(.*)/i
```

It will match both but I need just Name: ...

Please dont suggest any other way of finding, just please help me out with regex to work the way I described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave off the `i` modifier, which makes the regex case-insensitive.

And/or, add some word boundaries:

```
/\bName(:) (.*)\b/
```

Comment: That works! Thanks! What /b \b means can you explain more pls, i know that i is for case insensitive search, but if you remove just i and add ^ at the beginning it doesn't work..

Comment: @Santiago `/i` means that `/Name/i` matches any upper/lowercase variation of "Name", i.e. "name", "Name", "NAME", "NAme" etc. That's exactly what you *don't* want. `\b` is a word-boundary, which includes stuff like spaces, line endings, commas etc, i.e. anything that's *not* a "word character".

Comment: @Santiago I recommend http://rubular.com to play around with regexen and test many variations quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The `^` character will match the start of the line:

```
/^Name(:)(.*)/
```

Note, I've removed the `i` modifier, which makes your search case-insensitive.

Sample:

```
% cat ./test.php 
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

$regex = '/^Name(:)(.*)/';

$data = <<<EOD
Name: Santi
Surname: Dore
Name: Rob
Surname: Doe
and so on..
EOD;

foreach (explode("\n", $data, -1) as $line)
{
    if (preg_match($regex, $line, $matches))
    {
        printf("Found %s\n", $matches[2]);
    }
}


?>

% ./test.php
Found  Santi
Found  Rob
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/\b^(Name):\s[A-Z]+\s\b/
```

use `\s` for handling spaces.

Comment: Most welcome. Regular expression can solve many complicated things easily.